# about setActionCommand method

Tags: java, swing

I'm beginner in java

I need to know more about

```
button.setActionCommand(String command)
```

I need a command that read variable value, or read integers from text file

thanx in advance

Comment: You need to be much more precise than that. What are you trying to achieve? In what way do you need a button for it? What format is the text-file in and so on.

Comment: I'm trying to draw a dynamic line chart its x axis is time series and y axis is integers
to draw the line i need to take the integers from text file 10 by 10, calculate there average so the drawn point will be (current time , average ) .. the text file format is one integer number in each line .. so , i need a SetActionCommand that read the values from the files

Comment: Why not read the file first and store the contents in a variable and use that in your `JButton`s `actionPerformed(...)` method. Why so fussy about `setActionCommand(...)` ?

Comment: sounds like you have huge expectations as to what the framework can do for you :-) There is no command the _read ... whatever_, it's up to you to implement an Action which does what you require. Be sure to read and understand some introductory material about Swing, f.i. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's all you need to know about the `setActionCommand()` method in a `Button`, in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29). Now that we're at it, I'd rather recommend you use [`JButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) instead.

And please check a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), it's the best you can do when you're learning a new programming language.